# Haskell Non-Dominated sorting

Tags: haskell, sorting, genetic-algorithm

This algorithm sorts a list of Individuals, each with two fitness values, into what's called non-dominated fronts. A non-dominated front is a set of individuals where none of the individuals dominate each other. An individual is said to dominate another if is equal or lower (<=) for all fitness values and lower (<) in at least one fitness value. And so `[1,1]` dominates both `[1,2]` and `[2,1]`, but neither of the last two dominate each other. The rank of an individual indicates which front it is a member of. `[1,1]` would have rank 0; `[1,2]` and `[2,1]` would both have rank 1.

Non-dominant sorting is a small piece in bigger puzzles such as multi-objective optimization with genetic algorithms. If you are interested in how the algorithm works you can check out [Jensen 2003](http://delta.cs.cinvestav.mx/~ccoello/EMOO/jensen03.pdf), but I'm completely new to Haskell so I'm sure there's a lot to pick on without understanding squat about the actual algorithm. Here it goes:

RankSort.hs

```
module RankSort (
) where

import qualified Data.Vector as V

import           Genome
import           SortUtils

go :: String
go = let vind = Prelude.map toInd [(4,4),(2,3),(4,3),(1,1),(1,3),(2,1),(3,1),(1,1)]
         pool = V.fromList vind
         cmp x y = indCmpFit x y 0
         pool_s = poolSort pool cmp
         fronts = V.fromList [V.fromList []]
     in show $ rankSort pool_s fronts

rankSort :: Pool -> Fronts -> Fronts
rankSort pool fronts
  | V.length fronts == 1 && V.length (fronts V.! 0) == 0 = rankSort new_pool start_front -- start case
  | V.length pool == 1 = new_fronts --end case: sort the last remaining individual and return the sorted fronts
  | otherwise = rankSort new_pool new_fronts
  where
    new_pool = V.tail pool
    start_front = V.fromList [V.fromList [(pool V.! 0){ rank = 0 }]] -- first ind. always has rank 0
    upd_ind = rankIndex (V.head pool) fronts
    rank' = rank upd_ind
    upd_front = V.snoc (fronts V.! rank') upd_ind -- add individual to already existing front
    new_fronts = if rank' == V.length fronts
      then V.snoc fronts (V.fromList [upd_ind]) -- add a new front with ind as member
      else V.update fronts (V.fromList [(rank', upd_front)]) -- add individual to existing front


-- Take an individual and find the index of the front where it is not dominated by any members. This index is the rank.
rankIndex :: Ind -> Fronts -> Ind
rankIndex ind fronts
  | ind `domByFront` V.last fronts = ind { rank = V.length fronts }
  | otherwise = ind { rank = binSearch ind fronts 0 (V.length fronts - 1) }


-- Find the index of the front where the individual can be inserted without being dominated
-- Note that each individual in fronts[k] dominates at least one member of fronts[k+1].
-- Therefore the correct insertion point for an individual is k if
-- (ind `domByFront` fronts[k-1][-1]) and not (ind `domByFront` fronts[k][-1])
binSearch :: Ind -> Fronts -> Int -> Int -> Int
binSearch ind_a fronts low high
  | low == high = low
  | ind_b `dominates` ind_a = binSearch ind_a fronts (mid+1) high
  | otherwise = binSearch ind_a fronts low mid
  where
    mid = (low+high) `div` 2
    ind_b = V.last (fronts V.! mid)

-- Returns true of individual x dominates individual y; false if y dominates x or neither dominate each other
-- An individual x dominates an individual y if it is no worse in all objectives and strictly better in at least one.
-- For our problem, better means less.
dominates :: Ind -> Ind -> Bool
ind_a `dominates` ind_b = strictly_better && no_worse
  where
    strictly_better = V.or (V.zipWith (<) x y)
    no_worse = V.and (V.zipWith (<=) x y)
    x = fitnesses ind_a
    y = fitnesses ind_b

-- Returns whether or not an individual is dominated by any members of the front
domByFront :: Ind -> Pool -> Bool
ind `domByFront` front = V.any dom front
  where
    dom x = x `dominates` ind
```

Genome.hs

```
module Genome (
  Ind(fitnesses, genome, rank, cdist), Pool, Fronts,
  toInd, setRankP, setRankI, setCdistP, setCdistI, getFit
) where

import qualified Data.Vector                  as V
import           Data.Vector.Algorithms.Intro as VA
import qualified Data.Vector.Mutable          as VM

data Ind = Ind { fitnesses :: V.Vector Float
               , genome    :: String
               , rank      :: Int
               , cdist     :: Float -- Crowding distance
               }
type Pool = V.Vector Ind
type Fronts = V.Vector Pool

instance Show Ind where
   show Ind{ fitnesses = f, rank = r } = show f ++ "r" ++ show r

toInd :: (Float, Float) -> Ind
toInd (f1, f2) = Ind (V.fromList [f1, f2]) "" (-1) (-1)

setRankP :: Pool -> Int -> Int -> Pool
setRankP pool idx rank' = V.update pool (V.fromList [(idx, updInd)])
  where updInd = (pool V.! idx) { rank = rank' }

setRankI :: Ind -> Int -> Ind
setRankI ind rank' = ind { rank = rank' }

setCdistP :: Pool -> Int -> Float -> Pool
setCdistP pool idx cdist' = V.update pool (V.fromList [(idx, updInd)])
  where updInd = (pool V.! idx) { cdist = cdist' }

setCdistI :: Ind -> Float -> Ind
setCdistI ind cdist' = ind { cdist = cdist' }

getFit :: Pool -> Int -> Int -> Float
getFit pool indIdx fitIdx = fitnesses (pool V.! indIdx) V.! fitIdx
```

SortUtils.hs

```
module SortUtils (
  indCmpFit, poolSort
) where

import           Control.Monad.ST
import qualified Data.Vector                  as V
import           Data.Vector.Algorithms.Intro as VA

import           Genome

poolSort :: Pool-> (Ind -> Ind -> Ordering) -> Pool
poolSort pool cmp = runST (do
    v <- V.unsafeThaw pool
    VA.sortBy cmp v
    V.unsafeFreeze v)


-- Comparator to sort a list of individuals by increasing order of fitIdx
-- and for individuals with equal fitIdx, with increasing order of fitIdx+1
indCmpFit :: Ind -> Ind -> Int -> Ordering
indCmpFit x y fitIdx
  | a0 < b0 = LT
  | a0 > b0 = GT
  -- Can assume (fst x) == (fst y) beneath
  | a1 < b1 = LT
  | a1 > b1 = GT
  | a1 == b1 = EQ
  where
    f1 = if fitIdx == 0 then 0 else 1
    f2 = if fitIdx == 0 then 1 else 0
    a0 = fitnesses x V.! f1
    a1 = fitnesses x V.! f2
    b0 = fitnesses y V.! f1
    b1 = fitnesses y V.! f2
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a first tweak: Tighten recursion so there's fewer lines to read that contain recursion.

```
go :: String
go = let vind = Prelude.map toInd [(4,4),(2,3),(4,3),(1,1),(1,3),(2,1),(3,1),(1,1)]
         pool = V.fromList vind
         cmp x y = indCmpFit x y 0
         pool_s = poolSort pool cmp
     in show $ rankSort pool_s

rankSort :: Pool -> Fronts
rankSort = foldl new_fronts start_front where
  start_front = V.fromList [V.fromList [(pool V.! 0){ rank = 0 }]] -- first ind. always has rank 0
  new_fronts :: Fronts -> Ind -> Fronts
  new_fronts fronts ind = if rank' == V.length fronts
    then V.snoc fronts (V.fromList [upd_ind]) -- add a new front with ind as member
    else V.update fronts (V.fromList [(rank', upd_front)]) -- add individual to existing front
    where
      upd_ind = rankIndex ind fronts
      rank' = rank upd_ind
      upd_front = V.snoc (fronts V.! rank') upd_ind -- add individual to already existing front
```

Edit: Second: Shuffle arguments around so eta reduction is feasible. Also inline most stuff that's only used once.

```
indCmpFit :: Int -> Ind -> Ind -> Ordering
indCmpFit fitIdx x y

go :: String
go = let vind = Prelude.map toInd [(4,4),(2,3),(4,3),(1,1),(1,3),(2,1),(3,1),(1,1)]
     in show $ rankSort $ poolSort (V.fromList vind) (indCmpFit 0)
```

Comment: Should I inline stuff that's used many times, but only through recursion? I'm thinking about x and y in RankSort.dominates

Comment: There's something off with the first tweak: "Expected type: Fronts, Actual type: (V.Vector Fronts -> Fronts)". I'm not too familiar with folds to figure out what's what just yet. Maybe the syntax for V.foldl is different.

Comment: Ah, new_fronts is flipped. If the order in which the pool is passed to rankSort is irrelevant, replace foldl by foldr, otherwise swap around the arguments as I just edited in.

Comment: Yep, that works! The `start_front` needs to be empty otherwise the first individual will be added twice.